# какие службы надо отключить перед установкой Network Emulator?

Tags: сеть

У меня не хочет устанавливать Network Emulator. Ниже скрин ошибки.
"setup cannot not update system files or update shared files if they are in use. before proceeding we recommend that you close any applications you may be running"

[image: network emulator setup]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: setup cannot not update system files or update shared files if they are in use. before proceeding we recommend that you close any applications you may be running

Comment: @Артём Лисовский - а где Вы взяли это чудо? судя по скриншоту, оно ещё для 95 windows, если не для 3.11.

Comment: @KoVadim у меня задание по компьютерным сетям связано с этой программой

Comment: это очень хорошо, но может покажите более полное название этой программы и год ее выпуска? Но если программе больше 20 лет, то шанси ее нормально установить на современную винду сильно уменьшаются. А если она ещё хочет потрогать системные файлы... Лучше в виртуалбоксе поставить старую подходящую и там уже установить.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запустить установку от имени администратора с режимом совместимости с Windows XP.

Если не поможет:

1. Скачайте и установите VirtualBox
2. Скачайте образ Windows XP и установите его в VirtualBox
3. Перекиньте файл установки в виртуальную машину с Windows XP и попробуйте оттуда запустить установку